# How to solve this error in virtualbox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I have installed the virtual box and installing windows 10. and im getting this error

[image]

How to get solve this error and start installing win10

**Details**

[image]

Comment: Can you show the text for 'details' ?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, this is the only help I can find :-

1. Ensure the host machine is *FULLY* up to date
2. Reboot the machine
3. Uninstall Virtual Box
4. Reboot the machine
5. Reinstall Virtual Box

Source : [Link to Oracle article](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3639877)

---

I've found another couple of solutions on this :- [Forum Post with Error](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=33196)

```
I went into the folder "C:\Users\<YOUR_USERNAME>\.VirtualBox\Machines\VM_NAME\" and saw two xml files but for some reason they both had suffixes. 
1. VM_NAME.xml-prev
2. VM_NAME.xml-tmp
So it simply just couldn't find "VM_NAME.xml" because it technically didn't exist.
I made a copy of the "VM_NAME.xml-prev" file and renamed the copy to "VM_NAME.xml"
Restarted VirtualBox and it worked just fine.
```

There are some other solutions also listed.

Comment: details snapshot attached above. I have reinstall and reboot also same problem. Thanks